# Closing an Alert with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

Unable to close an alert which pop-ups once the url is navigated and enter something in the page(https://www.roadrunnersports.com).
I tried using sendkeys and using actions class aswell.
Manually, I am able to close the alert but I want to automate that aswell.

Anyone suggest me a way to handle this?

Note:Its not a sweet alert also to as I am unable to inspect the element.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and your code trials

Comment: I don't see any alert on the page. In general alert is controlable by: driver.switchTo().alert().accept(); resp. driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss(); In Chrome should work without switching the driver: alert().accept(); // alert().dismiss();

Comment: those are basics I have used  driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss() aswell. Once something is inputted then I am getting that alert

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it isn't consistently the same modal. But, the ones I've seen can be cleared by hitting the Esc key. Try using that with actions

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()
```

Make sure you wait for the modal to appear though, it seems like it takes a bit.

Comment: So which wait woupd be preferrable to use before the modal to appear

Comment: Wait for the modal element to appear. It's not popping up for me anymore so I can't tell you what that is. Just inspect it when you see it next.

Comment: Once the page loads and when you input something in the "Search" Editbox a pop-up is displayed.Morever, its not a sweet alert to inspect.

Answer (score 0):

Actions actions = new Actions(driver); // define action class
actions.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE).build().perform(); // Press ESC key